# How to make one function's if/else condition control other function in a structure?

Tags: c++, function, if-statement, struct

We got an assignment where we were supposed to make a birthday wisher. Now whenever the input for month date and year is invalid ( such as negative or zero or beyond the range of months and days) the program should not proceed forth. How to make it do that?

```
 #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;
   
   struct birthday_wisher {
       int date;
       int month;
       int year;
       int todaysdatedd,todaysdatemm;
   
      void getdob() {
           cout << "enter your date of birth (dd/mm/yy) " << endl;
           cin >> date >> month >> year;
           if ((todaysdatedd > 0 && todaysdatedd <= 31) && (todaysdatemm > 0 && todaysdatemm <= 12) && year>0 )
           {
               cout << "you have entered a valid date " << endl;
           }
           else
           {
               cout << "invalid date/ month\n";
           }
       }
      void gettodaysdate() {
          cout << "enter today's date (dd/mm)\n";
          cin >> todaysdatedd >> todaysdatemm;
          if ((todaysdatedd>0 && todaysdatedd<=31) && (todaysdatemm>0 && todaysdatemm<=12))
          {
              cout << "you have entered a valid date" << endl;
          }
          else 
          {
              cout << "invalid date/ month";
          }
      }
      void check() {
          if (month == todaysdatemm) {
              if (date == todaysdatedd)
              {
                  cout << "happy birthday!";
              }
          }
          else
          {
              cout << "your birthday is not today ;-;\n";
          }
      }
   };
   
   int main()
   {
       birthday_wisher b1;
       b1.getdob();
       b1.gettodaysdate();
       b1.check();
   }
```

Comment: Your functions either need to call `exit()` (to terminate the program) immediately when an invalid input is given or loop until they receive valid input.    If you change the functions so they return status (e.g. return a `bool` to indicate success or failure) your `main()` function can check the return value of the functions and terminate (or loop) as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You got a few options.

1. The brute option: Put `exit(int exitCode)` after the check fails. This will immediately exit the program e.g.

```
if (IsNotAValidDate())
{
    exit(1);
}
```

2. The better option: Make `getdob` to return bool and make the program peacefully exit if the condition fails.

```
bool getdob() {
    // You might want to check also for 31/30 day months and for February as here are bugs
    cout << "enter your date of birth (dd/mm/yy) " << endl;
    cin >> date >> month >> year;
    return (todaysdatedd > 0 && todaysdatedd <= 31) && (todaysdatemm > 0 && todaysdatemm <= 12) && year>0;
}

int main()
{
    birthday_wisher b1;
    if (b1.getdob())
    {
        b1.gettodaysdate();
        b1.check();
    }
    else 
    {
         std::cout << "Invalid date provided\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```